# Preview own posts if logged in

Tags: posts, previews

I want to make it so anyone logged in can view their own posts if draft or pending via the URL `?p=post_ID&preview=true`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use: `<?php get_author_posts_url( $author_id, $author_nicename ); ?>` on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url to get author own posts.

Comment: This outputs the link. I have this, but I need to know how a subscriber can view that post preview. What capability handles this?

Comment: Do you want to show all pending posts for an current user or one specific post (providing the id via url)?

Comment: One specific post. I have the list already and have a preview link, however, only editors and admins can see the preview. I want to know the specific capability is needed to view a post preview.